# Force SMS messages sent from static email address to use the same number (AT&T example)

Tags: php, email, sms, sms-gateway

This specific example is using AT&T as the carrier of the receiver.

When sending SMS messages to clients via their carrier email address (1234567890@txt.att.net) from a static email address, the messages arrive on the phone from a number in the format of `1 (400) 000-244`. Every time a new SMS message is sent, that number changes slightly. This causes phones, such as the iPhone, from properly threading the SMS messages that are coming from the same source email address.

Basic research shows that this has something to do with how AT&T's gateway handles turning emails into SMS messages. We've also looked at and decided that [Common Short Codes (CSC)](http://www.usshortcodes.com/csc_obtain_a_csc.html) are not worth $1000 per month to purchase, so this is not an option for us.

Does anyone know of another way around this limitation in which it would be possible to force all SMS messages from the same source email to appear that way on the phone so that they are threaded correctly?

In our configuration, the emails are going out via SMTP using the PHP [PEAR Mail_Mime](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime) package. We're really looking for a way we can do it on our end without the purchase of a shared or dedicated CSC.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't test this myself to see if there's a pattern, or if you can even control it. Check with AT&T themselves. In either case, you don't have to have a shortcode unless you also want to receive SMS. You can use a bulk SMS provider to send cheaply, regardless of carrier or even country: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4590638/cheapest-way-to-send-sms-for-number-verification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your AT&T issue <del>they use a cluster model to send out SMS using the email gateway. To over come your problem there might be a couple of solutions but it all depends on what your needs are</del> looks like they increment the phone number by one for each new message. Not sure how you could thread these.

[Zeep Mobile](http://www.zeepmobile.com/) lets you send SMS with a shared Short Code but they tag the end of your SMS message with ads, but the service is free (limited text per month I think)

[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) might be a good cheap alternative as they offer such services. No short code but I believe they use the same From number for your threading issue.

[Using your own GSM Modem](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=gsm+modem+for+sms&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) could be an option but there is some work on getting this to work properly. Also it uses a Long Code (Think telephone number) instead of a Short Code.

There are a couple of other solutions so I will update my answer soon.

UPDATE:

- [Tropo](https://www.tropo.com/home.jsp)
- [Google Voice](https://github.com/aaronpk/Google-Voice-PHP-API)

Comment: Twilio gives you dedicated 10-digit numbers that you can send and receive from using simple HTTP post requests. We have short codes in an early access program right now making their way toward publicly available. You can sign up on our site.

Comment: @John Sheehan where can you sign up for the short code early access program?

Comment: This is some good information and can most likely be beneficial to other people facing similar dilemmas, however we're just trying to get around AT&T's changing number without relying on a third-party services.

Answer (score 6):

**Use:**

> <10 digit phone number>@mms.att.net

Instead of 'txt.att.net'

This will solve the short code dilemma.

Comment: This renders the message a multimedia message instead of a text message, so depending on the plan and phone the recipient may be charged differently and/or the recipient might have other annoyances like having to confirm "downloading" each message. But this works well if those are not issues for that individual.